# dynamically LinkButton_Click or Button_Click are not invoked

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have made dynamically LinkButton, but when i click on it, the LinkButton_Click method isa not invoked???!!!

the codes are as follow:

```
LinkButton adtitle = new LinkButton();
adtitle.Text = "Title:" + GridView1.Rows[rowind].Cells[3].Text;
adtitle.OnClientClick += new EventHandler(method_to_call);
tcell_3.Controls.Add(adtitle);
trow_3.Controls.Add(tcell_3);
mytable.Controls.Add(trow_3);
this.form2.Controls.Add(adtitle);
```

and the method is:

```
private void method_to_call(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string email = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Email);
            string title = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Title1);
            string redirectUrl = "adpage.aspx?email=" + email + "&title=" + title + "&message=" + "Ad registered!";
            Response.Redirect(redirectUrl);
        }
```

as you see, in a webform, i create a table of controls and when i click on linkbutton control, it should transfer variables into another page (adpage.aspx)... but when i click, it stands in the same webform without table and it doesnt goes to adpage.aspx, why???!!!
i tried put the linkbutton in Page_Load, without any result (the same problem remains).
i dont know, it seems that something is null or empty... but what and how (with what) should i assign it?
thanks for your respond and kind regards

Comment: This does not even compile. Please review the documentation for `OnClientClick`. This property takes a string meant to be JavaScript.

Comment: hello... i have tried with adtitle.Click += new EventHandler(method_to_call); but the problem remains... something is null or empty... when i click on linkbutton, it works, but it doesnt invoke the method_to_call method???!!! this method must be assigned, but i dont know how and with what? appreciate your respond... kind regards

Comment: Try compiling your project. You will find that your code doesn't work as written. The compiler will tell you that it expects a string on the assignment of  `adtitle.OnClientClick`. You are trying pass an event handler.

Comment: hello again... i dont know how... can you make it for me, please? i changed it to adtitle.Click, but the same problem remains...

Comment: the compiler doesnt give any error... when i click, i stay in the same page (table is gone) not in the adpage, i would transfer the variables... why??!! i appreciate if you correct my codes... very kind regards

Comment: i have changed to: adtitle.OnClientClick = "adtitle_Click";
            //adtitle.Click +=new EventHandler(this.adtitle_Click);

Comment: but it doesnt invoke adtitle_Click method???!!!

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by using the clickable controls in Page_Init, then they worked very well...

Another solution is to delete the `If(!IsPostBack)` in the Page_Load, then the controls work properly.